# Show last item in ListBox

Tags: wpf, listview, .net-4.5

I have a bound listBox that is defined in XAML this way

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource lc_messageTemplateSelector}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMessage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" Background="White"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NakedListBoxItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <classes:ScrollIntoViewBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I do make a request to a web-service to get needed records and fill the Messages - ObservableCollection, all items are shown as needed, the problem I have, is after I load all the items I need to make visible the last one.
So I set it

```
SelectedMessage = Messages.Last();
```

By default this doesn't work using databinding, so I created (found it on SO) a behavior for this

```
public sealed class ScrollIntoViewBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += ScrollIntoView;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= ScrollIntoView;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        private static void ScrollIntoView(object o, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Selector selector = o as Selector;
            if (selector is ListBox)
            {
                (selector as ListBox).ScrollIntoView(selector.SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

What could be wrong here and how to make it work using data binding.

Could it be to the fact that some items have a complex DataTemplate which have the Image control that loads images in async mode and changes the size of the ListBox and then scrolling act wrong?

What I see is that sometimes it will show the last element, sometimes it will scroll to a random one, could not find a relation when it works the right way.

Thx

Comment: the problem is that you have variable size Items
i had the same problem once
i fixed by putting everything in a ScrollViewer and set the VerticalOffset to ActualHeight

Comment: so you put ListBox into ScrollViewer and set ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset ?
Can you show some sample code. 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScollViewer x:Name="scroller">
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox" SelectionChanged="selectionChanged"   
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
</ScrollViewer>`
```

then you have code-behind

```
private void selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
        var container = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listbox.SelectedIndex) as FrameworkElement;
        if (container == null) return;
        var transform = container.TransformToVisual(scroller);
        var elementLocation = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        double newVerticalOffset = elementLocation.Y + scroller.VerticalOffset;
        scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newVerticalOffset);
}
```

Comment: if you only need to scroll to the last one just do
`scroller.VerticalOffset = listbox.ActualHeight;`
or 
`scroller.VerticalOffset = scroller.ActualHeight;`

Comment: hm, that invokes lots of code behind, I'll see if I can change my Behavior class and use only binding. Thx

Comment: btw, scroller.VerticalOffset = newVerticalOffset; 
the VerticalOffset property has no setter, your code won't work. Are you sure that's what you've used?

Comment: sorry `scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newVerticalOffset);`

Comment: hm, something here is wrong
this line
var depObject = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listbox.SelectedIndex);
would return null after I set the SelectedIndex in my ViewModel .

Comment: In my context is more complex and i call these lines when `LayoutUpdated` i think that the problem is that the ListBox hasn't yet created all it's items, you should somehow wait for that to complete.

Comment: yeah, I guess this could be the case. I'll try to investigate.
And btw, after I enclose the ListBox into ScrollViewer the mouse wheel scrolling doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You should set up the ScrollViewer to show the vertical scrollbars that will do

Comment: The delay issue is somehow related to the `VirtualizingStackPanel`